# Using name of variable in .forEach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, variables

I'm working with JS/React, I currently have arrays nested into an array. The structure is as so:

```
const ezra = ["Patriots", "Bears", "Vikings", "Titans", "Jets", "Bengals"]
const adam = ["Chiefs", "Cowboys", "Packers", "Ravens", "Broncos", "Cardinals"]

const playerList = [ezra, adam]
```

I also have React states defined as follows:

```
this.state{
   ezraWins: 0
   adamWins: 0
}
```

I'm pulling data from React and using playerList.forEach to tally the total wins of the teams under each player. I'd like to find the total and .setState to change the value of${player}Wins to the total tallied. IE when I've totaled the wins by the teams of ezra I want:

```
this.setState({ezraWins: counter})
```

Here's a dumbed down example of how I thought it might work:

```
 playerList.forEach((player) => {
      const playerWins = `${player}Wins`
      const playerVariable = `${player}`
      //  use loop to tally total wins, add that to counter variable

      this.setState({${playerWins} : counter})
```

but when I console.log those variable I get:

playerList = Patriots,Bears,Vikings,Titans,Jets,BengalsWins

playerVariable = Patriots,Bears,Vikings,Titans,Jets,Bengals

Is there any way for me to pull the name of each array in playerList and use it for the .setState command in my code? I tried mucking a little with window as well but received an error I didn't write down, probably because I didn't make playerList and each array in there global. Is that the way to go about it or is there a better method? My understanding is that global variables are a no-no.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do string interpolation not in a string. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to end up with, though.

Comment: Do your work, then call `setState` _last_. Calling `setState` ten times in a row _overwrites_ the scheduled state update nine times and only the last one will "make it through". Also, you need to use `[]` if you want to set an object property name based on the value of some variable (e.g. `a = 'cow'; b = { [a]: 'moo' };`)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that got me halfway there, I'm trying to setState and it's not showing the desired value under my dev tools. I'm trying this.setState({ [playerName] : counter }) after counting for each player, I believe that's the correct syntax? I'll do some sleuthing from my end but if you see any obvious mistake I'd love to know!

Comment: Don't call setState for each player. Create an aggregate object like `update = {}`, then in your `forEach` you update _that_ and then after the loop you call `setState(update)`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm trying it with an array setData = [] I'm updating. tried hard coding the whole thing into a setState({ ezraWins: setData[0], adamWins: setData[1]}) and that didn't work either. Not sure why, but I'm far enough off topic that I'll play with it and ask another question if I can't figure it out. One random question I'm hoping you can answer, however:

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  Whenever I was running setState is my forEach loop it wouldn't update as [playerName] : counter, but it would update as an array if I did setState({[playerName] : [counter]}), showing a single value array in the Chrome Dev Tools. Any idea why on Earth that happened?

Comment: As I already mentioned, use an object, not an array. `let update = {}; forEach(player => { ... update[player.name] = counter; ... }) this.setState(update);` - no need for fancy var-content-as-name syntax, etc. Just use boring old JS but use _an object_ and set _its_ properties in your loop, then once you're done with the loop, a single setState, with that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a lot of retooling, but I found a better way to achieve the same result by putting all my data into the state. My final states looked like so:

```
          ezra: {name: "ezra", wins: 0, 
            teams: ["Patriots", "Bears", "Vikings", "Titans", "Jets", "Bengals"]},
          adam: {name: "adam", wins: 0, 
            teams: ["Chiefs", "Cowboys", "Packers", "Ravens", "Broncos", "Cardinals"]}
```

Per the suggestion of Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans I made an entire copy of my this.state at the beginning of my function:

```
let updateState = Object.assign({}, this.state)
```

and copied my win totals into the updateState variable in a as so:

```
updateState[player.name].wins = counter
```

where player is a copy of the state object of each player, i.e this.state.adam. There might be a better way to refer to the particular state object than my convention, where I gave it a name prop that was the same as the name of the state variable. It was the best I know how to do right now, however.

Finally, after I've looped through all the win totals and updated them to updateState, I updated the entire this.state with the following command:

```
this.setState(updateState)
```

Anyway, just wrote down how I solved this issue in case somebody stumbles upon this trying to accomplish a similar task I was. My solution deviated pretty far from my original question/code but I think it is a significantly better method.

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is that you are just using the player names only as the variable names.

Try saving the player names like this:

```
const ezra = {name: "ezra", teams: ["Patriots", "Bears", "Vikings", "Titans", "Jets", "Bengals"]}
```

and assign playerWins and playerVariable like this:

```
const playerWins = `${player.name}Wins`
const playerVariable = `${player.name}`
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: so to access the teams I'd use ezra.teams, and the name, ezra.name right? Let me play with that and see what happens.

Comment: Got me part of the way there, still having an issue with setState but at least in the console I'm logging the proper variable names and values. I was hoping to avoid using a JS object as an answer but that's probably the most concise method.

Comment: Hi, great. Actually I didn't exactly knew what you were trying to achieve. But now I see that you were trying to use the ezra variable name as a value. As I see it there's no possible way this could be achieved in js that's why I suggest you to change your code. As for the code inside the forEach statement as  Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans suggested you should use brackets {[playerWins] : counter} to use the value in playerWins for a new property, and call setState after finishing your loop as it would replace the state value for each iteration. Bye

Comment: yeah it was partially an issue with me being new and not knowing how to ask the question properly. If I did, I probably could've figured out a solution. A classic case of you don't know what you don't know I suppose. Thanks for the help in working me through a solution, your suggestion to turn my variables into JS objects over arrays was actually a pretty big contribution!